# Xcode 6 + xcodelegacy - Compiles Fine but Still Shows Errors

Tags: xcode, legacy

To be able to compile an Xcode project that contains some inline Intel assembler code in it, I have used the brilliant [xcodelegacy](https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy) by Frédéric Devernay. Using the LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler in Xcode 6, I am now able to compile and debug the application. The build shows only warning errors at this point, no fatal errors.

The assembler code is definitely being compiled, because I can step into it while in the debugger.

However, when you click on a file with the assembler instructions (i.e., _asm { } ), Xcode still shows fatal errors. I assume this is because the analyzer that scans these files (something like the old *Code Sense* I assume) is not using LLVM GCC 4.2.

I cannot figure out how to prevent these errors. While they do not impact my ability to work on this project, they are a bit annoying since they are not "real." Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for Frédéric Devernay?

Comment: Well, I think it is a general question about the difference between the compiler selection and the analyzer selection -- the latter of which i'm cannot find a method to change.

Answer (score 0):

Those are just editor problems. Either right-click on the file in Xcode and chose "Open Using External Editor", or open it with another editor (such as TextWrangler).